# What are the shortcut keys to lock screen on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, lock

Before Ubuntu 18.04, I could lock my screen by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> keys, but I cannot do it on 18.04.

Does anybody know what are the shortcut keys to lock screen on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: You can go to **setting -> Keyboard**, there, you can find all shortcuts of your system.

Comment: @PRATAP  Thanks for your edit, but there is also an option **accept and edit**, why didn't  you use that option?

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. <kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the key with Windows logo.

You can also change it to something you prefer using the **Settings** application (go to **Devices** > **Keyboard**).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is used as a shortcut for locking screen in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Windows key is known as Super key in Linux and BSD. See [Super key (keyboard button) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)#Linux_and_BSD)

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1108792/

Answer (score 0):

Its "Command" + "L" .  The command key is between the "Option/Alt" and "Space" key when using an English Apple Keyboard.